# Make a function that can take property of Action<T> or Action

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, action

I have the following 2 functions:

```
private void CallVoidFunction(Action action, object property = null)
{
    //Lots of code duplicated here 
    action.Invoke();
    //and here between teh 2 methods
}

private void CallVoidFunction<T>(Action<T> action, object property = null)
{
    //Lots of code duplicated here 
    action.Invoke((T)property);
    //and here between teh 2 methods
}
```

Is there a way to combine these into 1 function that takes a generic property of something `Action` ?
Otherwise I will have lots of duplicate code. I know I can combine the duplicate code into functions and call, but can it be done?

`Action` and `Action<T>` do not seem to derive from the same base so I assume it cannot be done?

I am thinking along the lines of an interface they derive from but I cannot see any common ground?

The best I can come up with is below, but I am hoping for a more simple way.

```
public class ActionContainer<T>
    {
        public ActionContainer(Action<T> actionT, Action action, object property)
        {
            _actionT = actionT;
            _action = action;
            _property = property;
        }

        public void Invoke()
        {
            if (_property != null)
                _actionT.Invoke((T)_property);
            else
                _action.Invoke();
        }

        private object _property { get; set; }
        private Action<T> _actionT { get; set; }
        private Action _action { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You could simplify the body of the first of those two down to: `CallVoidFunction<int>(i => { action(); }, 0);` Then you wouldn't need to repeat the code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen can you post an example please

Comment: `private void CallVoidFunction(Action action, object property = null)
{
    CallVoidFunction<int>(i => { action(); }, 0);
}`

Comment: Why are you declaring `property` as `object` then casting to `T`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay because that way I can call any method that takes 1 parameter

Comment: @Alex `CallVoidFunction<T>(Action<T> action, T property = null)` with `action.Invoke(property);` in body should work fine too, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Action<T>` represents a void function that takes 1 argument of type `T`, whereas `Action` represents a void function with no arguments.

You will therefore need to overload, because no function matches both signatures.

You can however, use a closure to avoid duplication:

```
private void CallVoidFunction<T>(Action<T> action, T property = default)
    => CallVoidFunction(() => action(property));

private void CallVoidFunction(Action action)
{
    //...
    action();
    //...
}
```

This wraps the function that accepts `T` in a function with no arguments.

You should also declare `property` as `T` rather than object to enforce type-safety.

---

If `property` is simply used as the argument to `action`, an alternative is to completely remove the generic version and have the caller formulate a closure instead.

If `CallVoidFunction` does need to use `property` in some way, then overloading is your only option:

```
private void CallVoidFunction<T>(Action<T> action, T property = default)
{
    // Do something with property..
    CallVoidFunction(() => action(property));
}
```

Comment: I think you must be using a newer version of C# comapred to me, based on your syntax?

Comment: I think `T property = null` should become `T property = default`

Comment: @Alex Possibly the [expresion bodied method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) which was introduced in C#6?

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Johnathan Barclay's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63485962/11178549), but in reverse. You start by implementing fully the generic version. Then the non-generic version can be derived from the generic one, passing a dummy `(object)null` argument.

```
private void CallVoidFunction<T>(Action<T> action, T property = default)
{
    //...
    action(property);
    //...
}

private void CallVoidFunction(Action action)
    => CallVoidFunction<object>(_ => action(), null);
```

The advantage is that the `property` is available in the full implementation, if you need it for some reason (like logging).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call first one from second one like this, so you will avoid code duplication:

```
private void CallVoidFunction<T>(Action<T> action, object property = null)
{
    CallVoidFunction(() => action.Invoke((T)property), property);
}
```

Comment: the type arguments for method..cannot be inferred

Comment: @Alex can you please add example code for this error?

Comment: It is exactly as you have it

Comment: removing the second property eg here: ((T)property), property); fixes it

Comment: @Alex it [works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HtWHvi)  for me.